# My server is blocked to SSH every day

Tags: linux, php, ssh

my problem is that i cant connect to my server trow SSH.
unless I do full restart to my server, and then, I can log in via SSH.
after about 24 hours (from the restart) , again I cant connect to my server via SSH.

using WHM cPanel server, Php ver 5.2.9, system linux

p.s.
FTP + web server works fine.
regards, or koren.

Comment: What type of Linux? Can you provide us some logs of auth/messages?

Comment: Doesn't give any information that can be used to resolve the problem sorry - I'd suggest contacting your hosting company. It could be anything from a memory issue through to SSH being firewalled automatically due to failed hacking attempts. I think you're best to contact your hosting company for support.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you telling us what version of PHP you are using? It would be a lot more help to know what sshd is running.

Did you read your logs for diagnostic messages? What are your iptables settings? Are you running fail2ban?

Since you've got PHP and the webserver is working, try writing a we script to see if the sshd is running / if the port is open.